# how to set a color to a value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, colors, matrix

Assume I have a matrix with integers.
I want to map a value to color.
For example, the value 0 will present as black, the value 0.5 will present as green etc.
I tried colormap but it doesn't work as I want.
In colormap, when i change a value in the matrix it effects other values as well.

So how can i map a color to a value?
a cell contains 0  presented as black.
a cell contains 0.5  presented as green.
a cell contains number equal or bigger than 1  presented as yellow.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't clear.  Please post some code that demonstrates what you're trying.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrix? Are you plotting a curve, an image, a surface?

Comment: Perhaps you could post an image of what your plot should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would think of doing anything like what you are saying is:

- Define a `colormap` as:

  cm = colormap([0 0 0; 0 1 0; 1 1 0]);
- Define a `caxis` as:

  caxis([0 1]);
- Use something like `pcolor` to represent your data.

All these is assuming that you want to represent some kind of color map in 2D. If you intend to plot a simple curve, but changing the color of the data points, you should do it manually, plotting them individually and setting the color manually for each point, depending on the value of the data:

```
% plot y versus x variable
for ii = 1:length(x)
    if y(ii) < 0.5
        color = [0 0 0];
    elseif y(ii) < 1
        color = [0 1 0];
    else
        color = [1 1 0];
    end
    plot(x(ii), y(ii), '.', 'Color', color);
    hold on;
end
hold off;
```